# How do you check an email server (gmail) for a certain address and run something based on that address?

Tags: python, email, pop3

I've been trying to use 'import poplib' to access gmail, since I have Pop turned on in settings- but how do I actually then check the message for its 'from' address and then run something based on it? Also, what would be the command to strip the 'body' text from the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get subject and sender of each message in your GMail inbox using imaplib.

```
import imaplib
from email.parser import HeaderParser

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
conn.login('username@gmail.com', 'password')

# Select the mail box
status, messages = conn.select('INBOX')

if status != "OK":
    print "Incorrect mail box"
    exit()

if int(messages[0]) > 0:

    for message_number in range(1,int(messages[0])+1):  
        data = conn.fetch(message_number, '(BODY[HEADER])')
        parser = HeaderParser()
        msg = parser.parsestr(data[1][0][1])
        print "Subject: %s" % msg['subject']
        print "From: %s" % msg['from']
```

You will probably need more information. Start from the [official imaplib documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much! imaplib worked a hundred times better than poplib.

Answer (score 0):

there is the module rfc822

I guess messages from poplib can be donloaded from the server.

then put into a file

```
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO(message)
>>> import rfc822
```

and passed to

```
>>> rfc822.Message(f)
```

try this out.. and also check out the module documentation.
I hope it helps.

---

There is another python module:

```
>>> import email
>>> email.message_from_string(...)
```

This should provide you with read access for headers and also support muliple formats of body contents.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html):

```
POP3.retr(which)

Retrieve whole message number which, and set its seen flag. Result is in form (response, ['line', ...], octets).
```

So, assuming you have put the result of `retr()` into a variable called `response`, the lines of the message are stored as a list in `response[1]`. By [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) we know that the headers are separated from the body of the message by a blank line. The sender of the message will be in the `From:` header line. So we can just iterate over the lines of the message, stop when we get a blank line, and set a variable to our sender when we see a line that starts with `From:`.

```
sender = None
for line in response[1]:
    if line.startswith("From: "):
        sender = line.partition(" ")[2].strip()
    elif line == "":
        break
```

If you plan to do a lot with the headers, it might be useful to put them into a dictionary by header name.  Since each header can appear multiple times, each value in the dictionary should be a list.

```
 headers = {}
 for line in response[1]:
     if line == "":
        break
     line = line.partition(" ")
     key = line[0].strip().rstrip(":")
     value = line[2].stirp()
     headers.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

After this you can use `headers["From"][0]` to get the sender of the message.

I wanted to show the basic way of doing this, because it's not very complicated, but Python can do most of the work for you. Again, assuming that your `retr()` result is in `response`:

```
 import email

 # convert our message back to a string and parse it
 headers = email.parsefromstring("\n".join(response[0]), headersonly=True)
 print headers["From"]  # prints the sender
```

You can find out more about the message object in the documentation for the [email module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html).

The `From:` line of an e-mail message may have additional text besides the e-mail address, such as the sender's name. You can extract the email address with a regular expression:

```
sender = re.find(r".*[ <](.+@.+)\b", headers["From"]).match(1)
```